# Error when writing data to Excel using OleDb C# : this table contains cells that are outside the range of cells defined in this spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I don't know why I keep getting the error:

> 'This table contains cells that are outside the range of cells defined
>   in this spreadsheet'

I'm trying to write data which is received serially from a sensor to an Excel document. I've tried using both the "INSERT INTO" and "UPDATE" statements, both of which don't seem to work. I'm hoping someone could shed some light on what could be the problem and provide a hint for a possible solution.

I finally managed to partially fix the problem by tweaking the code a lot but now the problem is that the same error occurs but just after the program writes the data into the first and second row of the excel file, when its about the write in the third row, it outputs the error instead; note however this problem occurs for excel files with .xls extensions.

But when I tried it with the .xlsx files, it seems that the program is only able to write in the first row before outputting the same error when it attempts to write in the second row. Any suggestions, to what I may have done wrong?

Thanks.

Below is the code:

```
private void ProcessRxdSerialData(string rxdSerialData, int rxdSerialVal)
    {

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rxdSerialData))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rxdSerialData);
                HandleRxdSerialDataResponse(rxdSerialData);

                TimeElapsed = TimeElapsed + 1;
                m_mainForm.PlotGraphs(rxdSerialVal, TimeElapsed);

                string columnSelect = "A";

                m_mainForm.XlsxWrite(rxdSerialData, m_mainForm.DataStorageFileLocation, columnSelect);
            }

        } //try

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }



 public void XlsxWrite(string rxdSerialData, string dataStorageLocation, string columnSelect)
    {
        try
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                   delegate
                   {
                       if ((checkBoxEnableWriteToExcel.Checked) &&
                           (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxDataStorageLocation.Text)))
                       {
                           RowCount = RowCount + 1;
                           WriteRxdSerialDataToExcel(rxdSerialData, dataStorageLocation, RowCount, columnSelect);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           RowCount = 0;
                       }
                   }));
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }


public void WriteRxdSerialDataToExcel(string rxdSerialData, string dataStorageLocation, int timeElapse, string columnSelect)
    {
        int row = timeElapse;
        string column = columnSelect;

        //Converting Row integer to string
        string rowStr = row.ToString();

        //Open Excel File to conduct Write/Update process
        string fileLocation = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dataStorageLocation +
                                  @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; HDR=No;IMEX=3;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0"""; //for reading data IMEX = 1, for writting data IMEX = 3
        OleDbConnection pathConnection = new OleDbConnection(fileLocation);
        pathConnection.Open();

        //write the data into the Excel Spread sheet
        string rowColumnCoordinate = String.Concat(column, rowStr);
        string excelWrite = String.Format("UPDATE [Sheet1${0}:{0}] SET F1='{1}'", rowColumnCoordinate, rxdSerialData);
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(excelWrite, pathConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        pathConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear from that code, but I have suspicion that you are trying to write excel from [0,0] cell, and excel is [1,1] based.

Comment: I checked that but it doesn't seem so, any other suggestions?

Comment: Not many. Excel 2007 (12.0) has around 1000000 rows and 16000 columns, and excel 2003 has only 16000 rows and 256 columns.  If your database is big enough, it can be the reason.

Comment: I finally managed to partially, by tweaking the code a lot but now the problem is that the same error occurs but just after the program writes the data into the first and second row of the excel file, when its about the write in the third row, it outputs the error instead; note however this problem occurs for excel files with .xls extensions. But when I tried it with the .xlsx files, it seems that the program is only able to write in the first row before outputting the same error when it attempts to write in the second row. Any suggestions, to what I may have done wrong?

Comment: I also edited my post and added the other methods which are related to the one I posted previously. Hopefully it will help clarify things out. Thanks